# aligning img and h1 no matter the size of the webpage

Tags: css

Trying to put image (logo) next to text (business name) in the header.  Looks fine when the page is small, but when the page takes up a larger computer screen the image and text have too much space in-between.

Trying to get the text to stay centered on page and the image to align itself just to the left of the text.

```
 <style>
img {
  float: left;
   width: 90px;
   height: 90px;
   padding-left: 16%;
  }
h1 {
  color: #0C234B;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 50%;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 197%;
  }
 </style>

<header>
 <img src="logo.png"/>
   <h1>Name of Business</h1>
 </header>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that this will give you what you want:

```
<style>
  img {
    width: 90px;
    height: 90px;

    position: absolute;
    left: -90px;
  }
  h1 {
    color: #0C234B;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 197%;

    display: inline-block;
    width: auto;
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 10px;
  }

  header {
    text-align: center;
    min-width: 500px; /* Optional */
  }
</style>

<header>
  <h1><img src="logo.png" /> Name of Business</h1>
</header>
```

The important features are that the text is still exactly centered (because `position: absolute` on the image removes it from the page flow), but the distance between the image and the logo is fixed by `h1` padding.

Comment: Thank you.  I used most of your coding.  Changed a few things and it worked perfectly.  In the style for img I added padding-top: 20px; and left out the left: -90px;.Changed the h1 style padding-left to 100px instead of 10px because the h1 was overlapping on the image (business name is a little long....) and took out min-width in the header style.  Thank you again. Helped me so much!

Answer (score -1):

`margin-left: auto;` should be the cause.